# How to select row index along with its elements of a list?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a list of following class:

```
Class Test
{

int A;
String B;
Char C;
}

List<Test> obj:

10  “Abc”   'a'
29  “Bcd”   'b'
36  “Cde”   'c'
45  “Def”   'd'
51  “Efg”   'e'
```

I want a linq Query that will give me output like this:

```
1   “Abc”
2   “Bcd”
3   “Cde”
4   “Def”
5   “Efg”
```

Comment: is `1,2,3..` just a counter next to the record?

Comment: @christiandev: No, otherwise it would have been easier.

Comment: I mean, are you applying **1** next to **Abc** as that's the **first record**, **2** next to **Bcd** as that's the **second** etc...?

Comment: @christiandev: No that isn't the case. First column can contain any integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `new` with an anonymous class to obtain a projection; use [the override of `Select` that gives you the item number to produce the row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
var projection = obj.Select((o,i) => new {Index = i+1, Value=B});
foreach (var item in projection) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} “{1}”", item.Index, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Column A doest contain row nos, it can be any integer.

Comment: What if i have to select C too?

Comment: `new { Index = i+1, Value = B, AnotherValue = C }` or `new { Index = i+1, Value = B + " " + C}`